# Equivalence of Harmonic Maps and Conformal Maps on Genus-0 closed surfaces

Tags: riemannian-geometry, harmonic-analysis, riemann-surfaces, conformal-geometry, harmonic-functions

By the uniformization theorem, for every genus-0 closed surface $\mathcal{M}\subset\mathbb{R}^3$, there is a conformal map $f:\mathcal{M}\rightarrow \mathbb{S}^2$. Furthermore consider the Dirichlet Energy
$$E(f)=\int_{\mathcal{M}}\left|\nabla f\right|^2\:d\lambda_{\mathcal{M}}.$$
A critical point of this energy functional is called harmonic map. Now the intersting statement is:

For a genus-0 closed surface $\mathcal{M}$, the conformal maps $f:\mathcal{M}\rightarrow\mathbb{S}^2$ are equivalent to the harmonic maps.

Can you please provide a source with a rigorous prove of this statement, or a short explanation as to why it holds?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think it is a very good exercise to show that a conformal map between Riemann surfaces (equipped with metrics in the conformal classes) are harmonic.

The converse direction is more interesting, and does depend on the assumption that  the domain is  a compact surface of genus $0.$ In general, one can consider for  maps $f\colon M\to S^2$ the so called Hopf differential which is given in a local holomorphic coordinate $z$ on $M$ as $$Q=<\frac{\partial f}{\partial z},\frac{\partial f}{\partial z}>(dz)^2.$$
It turns out that $f$ is harmonic if and only if $Q$ is holomorphic. On a surface of genus $0$ there do not exist any non-zero holomorphic quadratic differentials, so under your assumption, $Q=0.$ By looking at the definition of $Q$ this implies conformality.
Besides the book of Helein mentioned by Paul, the book "Riemannian Geometry and Geometric Analysis" by Jost contains the details of these computations.

Comment: Thank you, Sebastian, for your excellent answer. The book of Jost indeed goes through all the details nicely.

Comment: Dear Skrodde, you are welcome.

Answer (score 5):

MR0164306 (29 #1603) Reviewed 
Eells, James, Jr.; Sampson, J. H.
Harmonic mappings of Riemannian manifolds. 
Amer. J. Math. 86 1964 109–160.

Example on p. 118

Comment: Thank you, Igor, for your reply to my question. However, I fail to see how any of the three examples given on page 118 fits my problem.
In the first example, the authors suppose $M'$ to be flat, where I need $M'=\mathbb{S}^2$. In the second example, they  only establish $f$ homomorphism $\Rightarrow$ $f$ harmonic. But not the converse and conformal maps don't even enter the picture here. Finally, in the third example it is $f$ holomorphic $\Rightarrow$ $f$ harmonic, but again not the converse, which I would need.
Could you maybe clarify a little? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

There is also the [excellent book](https://books.google.fr/books?hl=en&lr=&id=1RgjnAq7Y0oC&oi=fnd&pg=PR9&dq=Harmonic%20maps,%20conservation%20laws%20and%20moving%20frames,&ots=h_AiQifeZY&sig=HXL-OW8IaTbugZuMRqYrpnLxfoQ#v=onepage&q=Harmonic%20maps%2C%20conservation%20laws%20and%20moving%20frames%2C&f=false) of Frederic Helein which will provide you many good references.